# PHP if single or double equals

Tags: php, if-statement, equals

For checking if one string matches another I've been using double equals sign up to now. e.g.

```
if ($string1==$string2)
```

This is because most of the strings I've been using are alphanumeric. However now I am trying the same thing with numeric values like this:

```
 $string1 = 10;
 $string2 = 10;
```

Questions is, do I do a single equal or a double equal to make sure the two strings match 100% not more not less just exact

So do I do:

```
if ($string1==$string2)
```

or

```
if ($string1=$string2)
```

Comment: Single `=` is __assignment__; double `==` is __loose comparison__ (with typecasting); triple `===` is __strict comparison__ (datatypes must match)

Answer (score 8):

Double equals (`==`) is probably what you want to use for that comparison. (You can also use triple equals i.e. `===` for 'strict' comparison, so that `"2" === 2` will be false.)

A single equals sign is an assignment: it overwrites the left hand side, and then your `if` statement would be just equivalent to checking the value that wound up being assigned (e.g. the value of the right hand side).

For example, this will print `It's not zero!` followed by `foo = 1` (as you'd expect):

```
$foo = 1;
if ($foo == 0) {
  print("It's zero!");
} else {
  print("It's not zero!");
}
print("foo = " + $foo);
```

But this will print `It's not zero!` followed by `foo = 0` (probably not what you expect):

```
$foo = 1;
if ($foo = 0) {
  print("It's zero!");
} else {
  print("It's not zero!");
}
print("foo = " + $foo);
```

The reason is that in the second case, `$foo = 0` **sets** `$foo` to 0, and then the `if` is evaluated as `if($foo)`. Since `0` is a false value, the `else` statement is run.

Answer (score 4):

The *identical to* operator, `===`, is used when you want to compare two operands' values **and** types.

The *equal to* operator, `==`, is used when you want to compare two values. It will evaluate to `true` if [both values are *equivalent*](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) (i.e. `15 == "15"` would be `true`).

The assignment operator, `=`, is used to assign a value to a variable. This operator should not be used for comparing values; that is not what it is for.

Now, for comparing strings in various ways you may want to look at the [`strcmp` family of functions](http://php.net/strcmp). They are very useful for comparing strings in a variety of ways.

Answer (score 0):

```
$a === $b   TRUE if $a is equal to $b, and they are of the same type.
```

More info: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php