# How to check to see if a wordpress shortcode $atts is equal to something

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I am trying to figure out how to figure out how to check to see if a shortcode attribute is equal something and than if it is set a variable.

I have an image shortcode with an attribute of float and I want to set a class to float right if the user enters in float="right" as an attribute but if not than do nothing.

```
add_shortcode( 'img', 'img_shortcode' );
function img_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
$atts = shortcode_atts(
array(
    'float' =>'',
), $atts);

$ImgFloat = '';

if(float attribute = right){
        $ImgFloat = 'class="img-right"';
    }

return '
<div class="img-shortcode">
    <img '. $ImgFloat .' src="'. $content .'" />
</div>
';
}
```

Above is the shortcode, as you can see the If statement is where I'm having the trouble, I would like to figure out how to check to see if the attribute float is set to anything if it is set to right, than make $imgFloat variable equal to the float right class that I have set.

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
if(float attribute = right){
        $ImgFloat = 'class="img-right"';
}
```

To this:

```
if ( 'right' == $atts['float'] ) {
    $ImgFloat = 'class="img-right"';
}
```

OK so I may have complicated the answer by flipping the conditional around but it's a good habit to get into :)

The important part is we're saying if `$atts['float']`, which is the value of float="" in the shortcode, is equal to right then add the class.

`shortcode_atts(...` at the top of the function is where `$atts['float']` is given a default value. If the user doesn't enter float=".. then the value is a blank string.

Comment: Was going to say `right` should be `'right'` but you beat me to it with your edit :)

Answer (score 0):

[`shortcode_atts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/shortcode_atts) returns an array combining the parameters passed in with the defaults you specify.  So the float attribute will be stored in `$atts['float']`

Comment: So I would use  if($atts['float'] = 'right') correct?

Comment: Use two equals signs (`==`), not one.  Two checks for equality, one assigns the value to the variable.  What you have there will set `$atts['float']` to 'right', losing the original value, and always executing the code in your `if` block (since PHP will do `if('right')`, and 'right' is "truthy".  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20275032/php-if-single-or-double-equals and "Converting to boolean" [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php)).

Comment: The `==` versus `=` is why in @Nathan Dawson's answer he has `'right' == $atts['float']`, not `$atts['float'] == 'right`.  If you accidentally only type one (`'right' = $atts['float']`), PHP will throw an error, since you can't assign a value to a literal.  An error's much better than a hard to find bug because of missing `=`.