# Wordpress foreach if statement shows all users where only one is expected?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom field in my wordpress user profile : instrument

I have two users with the role subscriber. One hav the instrument Altosaxofon and one Tenorsaxofon.

With this code I want to display "Tenorsaxofon", but I get "TenorsaxofonTenorsaxofon"

```
<?php
$args1 = array('role' => 'subscriber');
$subscribers = get_users($args1);
foreach ($subscribers as $user) {
    if ( $user->instrument = 'Tenorsaxofon' )
    {
        echo $user->instrument ;
    }
}
?>
```

Why is that?

Best regards, Kresten

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you're using a single equals (`=`) instead of a double equals (`==`) to check the person's instrument. A single equals (`=`) signifies an assignment, and it returns true if the assignment worked. I think you want to use a double equals (`==`) to instead check if `$user->instrument` is the same as `Tenorsaxofon`.

If this is the case, you'll want to change this:

```
if ( $user->instrument = 'Tenorsaxofon' )
```

To this:

```
if ( $user->instrument == 'Tenorsaxofon' )
```

(More about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20275032/php-if-single-or-double-equals)).

---

It also could be that `$subscribers` contains two users who have their instrument set to `Tenorsaxofon`. If there's two subscribers with the same instrument, then your `echo` will print `Tenorsaxofon` twice, resulting in `TenorsaxofonTenorsaxofon`

Answer (score 1):

try this, your missing a = sign $user->instrument == 'Tenorsaxofon'

```
<?php    
$args1 = array('role' => 'subscriber');
$subscribers = get_users($args1);
foreach ($subscribers as $user) {
    if ( $user->instrument == 'Tenorsaxofon' )
    {
        echo $user->instrument ;
    }
}
```